# Unable to click to a hyperlink to https://www.asic.gov.au

Tags: excel

I created an Excel file (test.xlsx) using the Excel for Office 365.

I then entered the following URLs on columns A1, A3, A5, A7

https://www.accc.gov.au

https://www.apra.gov.au

https://www.ato.gov.au

https://www.asic.gov.au

These URLs are the homepage to the websites belonging to Australian government agencies ACCC, APRA, ATO and ASIC.

When I click on the column A1, A3 and A5 ... the corresponding homepage of the website ACCC, APRA and ATO will open on the browser accordingly.

However, when I click on the column A7, I got the following error message:
"Unable to open http://www.asic.gov.au. Cannot download the information you requested."

If I type in the URL https://www.asic.gov.au on a browser, then the homepage to website ASIC will open without any problem.

I have googled for tips and solutions and tried a few but none worked so far.

Can someone please help me with this problem?

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/the_microsoft_excel_support_team_blog/2011/11/15/cannot-download-the-information-you-requested-executing-web-query-from-excel/

Comment: I did the following as mentioned in the article but still does not work.

Go to START and in the RUN line type REGEDIT. In the registry navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings. Right click Internet Settings and left click New > DWORD Value (32-bit) and name the new value “BypassSSLNoCacheCheck” without the quotes. Double click this value and give it a value of 1.